# What database field type do you use for yes/no entries in SQL Buddy?

Tags: mysql, sql, types, sqlbuddy

I am new to all this so looking for some help. Sorry if the question is really novice. I am learning all of the char, varchar, etc.

Comment: FYI, if my answer solved your problem, you should click the checkmark next to it to mark it 'accepted'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `BOOL`.  (It's an alias for `TINYINT(1)`.)

If the MySQL server is at least version 5.0.3, you can also use `BIT` (or `BIT(1)`, same thing).

You'd probably benefit from checking out [some of the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html).